# Randomly Generate Directed Graph on a grid

Tags: language-agnostic, random, graph-theory, maze

I am trying to randomly generate a directed graph for the purpose of making a puzzle game similar to the ice sliding puzzles from pokemon.

This is essentially what I want to be able to randomly generate: http://bulbanews.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Crunching_the_numbers:_Graph_theory

I need to be able to limit the size of the graph in an x and y dimension. In the example in the link, it would be restricted to an 8x4 grid.

The problem I am running in to is not randomly generating the graph, but randomly generating a graph which I can properly map out in a 2d space, since I need something (like a rock) on the opposite side of a node, to make it visually make sense when you stop sliding. The problem with this is sometimes the rock ends up in the path between two other nodes or possibly on another node itself, which causes the entire graph to become broken.

After discussing the problem with a few people I know, we came to a couple of conclusions that may lead to a solution. Including the obstacles in the grid as part of the graph when constructing it. Start out with a fully filled grid and just draw a random path and delete out blocks that will make that path work, though the problem then becomes figuring out which ones to delete so that you don't accidentally introduce an additional, shorter path. We were also thinking a dynamic programming algorithm may be beneficial, though none of us are too skilled with creating dynamic programming algorithms from nothing. Any ideas or references about what this problem is officially called (if it's an official graph problem) would be most helpful.

Comment: Nice question, but probably more appropriate for the Programmers SE site.
My intuition would be not to try to generate the graph, but to start with random placement of the obstacles and then derive the graph from them.

Comment: I attempted that as well and I end up with having to rerun it a bunch of times to get a good one. Good being defined by the number of steps to solve from start to finish. And it takes awhile as it's just brute forcing a solution essentially. I'll ask again in Programmers SE as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't look at it as a graph problem, since as you say the representation is incomplete. To generate a puzzle I would work directly on a grid, and work *backwards*; first fix the destination spot, then place rocks in some way to reach it from one or more spots, and iteratively add stones to reach those other spots, with the constraint that you never add a stone which breaks all the paths to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to generate a [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph), which means that the edges of the graph will not overlap each other in a two dimensional space. Another definition of planar graphs ist that each planar graph does not have any subgraphs of the type K_3,3 (complete bi-partite with six nodes) or K_5 (complete graph with five nodes).

There's a [paper](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/plantri-full.pdf) on the fast generation of planar graphs.